# Trying to establish a connection in xamarin VS 2019

Tags: xamarin

I’m trying to establish a connection with a Web Service already running with Visual Studio 2019 community.  The connection is already establish on Visual Studio but when trying to use it I got CS0119 error ‘UsuariosSoap’ is a type, which is not valid int given context.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using System.Net;
    using UsuarioWS;

    namespace XamarinWSMobile
    {
        // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
        // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
        [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
        {
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void AnadirUsuario(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //establece la conexion con el web service
                UsuarioWS.UsuariosSoap usuarioWS = UsuarioWS.UsuariosSoap;
                usuarioWS.GuardarUsuarioAsync(this.Nombre.Text, this.Apellidos.Text,this.Direccion.Text, this.Pueblo.Text, this.ZipCode.Text, this.FechaNac.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling UsuariosSoap is a `Type` so this is wrong:

```
UsuarioWS.UsuariosSoap usuarioWS = UsuarioWS.UsuariosSoap;
```

In order to use it, you need to create an instance of the service, the `UsuariosSoap` class, before using it.

Replace the line above with this:

```
UsuarioWS.UsuariosSoap usuarioWS = new UsuarioWS.UsuariosSoap();
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: I changed the line as you suggest but now the error code changed; CS0144 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface ‘UsuariosSoap’  
I had made this with VB.Net a lot of times, but with Xamarin and C# I haven’t been able to accomplish it.
Thanks for your help

Comment: that's pure OOP. If that class if abstract you will not be able to create an instance of it hence the error message. Do you have access to the code for the WebService? Is there another class that you can instantiate?